# .Net Framework 1.1 and SQL Server 2014 or 2016

Tags: ado.net, sql-server-2014, .net-1.1, sql-server-2016

does anyone knows if a .net framework 1.1 application that uses ado.net will still work if I upgrade the SQL Server database from 2008 to 2014 or 2016?

Comment: One way to find out real quick...

Comment: Based on my experience, you will have problems